# What is the time complexity of the algorithm to check if a number is prime?

Tags: algorithms, complexity, numbers

What is the time complexity of the algorithm to check if a number is  prime?

This is the algorithm :

```cpp
bool isPrime (int number) { 
    if (number < 2) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i=3; (i*i) <= number; i+=2) {
        if (number % i == 0 ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you loop from 3 to `sqrt(number)`, this is enough info for you to figure out the rest...

Comment: Also, you only need to divide by the primes you've already calculated (granted this means keeping a list of said primes). e.g. you can skip diving something by 9, if it's divisible by 9 it's also divisible by 3, and you'll already have tried to divide it by 3.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O(sqrt(n)) in the magnitude of the number, but only as long as you use `int`

Note that complexities for prime number related algorithms are often discussed with n as the *length* (in bits) of the number - and that you cannot assume things like comparing, adding, modulor or multiplying to be O(1), because with arbitrariy-precision numbers these operations become more expensive with the size of the number.

The [best currently known algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) runs in O((log n)^6)

Comment: The fastest known algorithm is to use a pre-computed bit field. It's O(1), but costs "(max_number/2 + 7)/8" bytes (e.g. 128 MiB for 32-bit signed integers).

Comment: @Brendan: Using precomputed results does not constitute an algorithm, at least not without specifying how you get those precomputed results and including that computation in the time analysis.

Comment: If you're suggesting that "Big O" has no practical value whatsoever, then I agree; but I'd still say an algorithm to find the right bit in a bitfield is an algorithm (and that more complex algorithms involving multiple bitfields can form the basis of an entire branch of mathematics - predicate logic).

Comment: No - Big O has **A LOT** of practial value. My point is that looking up a precomputed solution to X is *not* an algorithm that solves X unless you include the steps to do the precomputation. Suggesting otherwise is very similar to the apocryphal Marie Antoinette quote that people rioting because they have no bread should just eat cake.

Comment: That's an entirely broken way of looking at it. If you do `uint8_t myBitfield = 0x12` in your code; do you have to include the algorithm used to generate the 8-bit bitfield?

Comment: @Brendan: That way of looking at it is not even broken, it's completely missing the problem. You cannot solve an arbitrarily scalable problem by assuming that the solution already exists and you just have to look it up. The largest known prime number is 2^57,885,161 − 1. Now I want to know whether 2^57,885,715 − 1 is prime. How is "look it up in a bitfield" going to do that?

Comment: It's not missing the problem. The problem (as stated by the original poster) is `bool isPrime(int number)`. By completely ignoring the original problem you end up ignoring practical alternatives that are "O(1)".

Comment: Also note that if you're willing to ignore all practical considerations (like the range of numbers and the different costs of different operations); then I'm happy to have a bitfield with 2^57,885,715 bits.

Comment: @Brendan: If you really want to split hairs: the original poster wanted to know the time complexity of his specific code and was not interested in alternatives at all. But "look up a precomputed solution" is still not an algorithm, and it's completely meaningless to talk about Big-O when your solution only works on a size-limited version of the problem.

Comment: Are you suggesting that AKS primality test will work in practice with a number of unlimited size?

Comment: @Brendan: sure - it's just a matter of how long you're willing to wait.

Comment: So a 2^57,885,715 bit number would be fine for AKS, but a 2^57,885,715 bit bitfield is out of the question. Sounds like someone's making up arbitrary limits to me.

Comment: @Brendan: how can you possibly still miss the point: where does the value of that bitfield come from? Magic? And once you have hit, your lookup still only works for numbers up to that limit, whereas an actual algorithm does not have such a limit.

Comment: Same place your code comes from - files. If you want to count the code that generated the files, then we can estimate the Big O for your compiler if you like.

Comment: @Brendan: This discussion is pointless. You have clearly demonstrated that you have no idea what the word "algorithm" even means.

Comment: Let's summarize. A constant integer (or bitfield, same thing) may or may not be counted depending on how big it might be; the contents of files may or may not count depending on what mood you're in; limits may or may not be ignored depending on whether it helps your argument; "operations" may be tiny or huge (e.g. bignum library) and they still only count as one operation; things that matter (like cache/memory/disk hierarchy) are ignored; and despite all of this Big O notation is meant to have some sort of practical value..

Comment: In practice we use probabilistic algorithms with runtime O((log n)^3) (or slightly lower if you use fancy multiplication algorithms) instead of AKS.

Comment: `O(sqrt(n))` is ambiguous, because `n` is not the size of the input.

Answer (score 2):

Worst case - when the number is prime - is quite obvious O(sqrt(n))
Best case happens when number can be divided by 2,3,5,7,9. In these cases we will terminate the loop pretty soon in finite number of steps - O(1)

Now lets compute full average case for the algo:

On the interval [0,n] there are aprox n/ln(n) prime numbers.

The algo hits prime with probability of P1=1/ln(n)

The other numbers with probability of P2=1-ln(n)

Average case is O(sqrt(n))*1/ln(n)+O(1)*(1-ln(n))
We get rid of smaller part

```
=O(sqrt(n))/ln(n)
```

move ln(n) inside O()

```
=O(sqrt(n)/ln(n))
```

base of logarithm does not matter for big-O notation

```
= O(sqrt(n)/log(n))
```

Comment: Composite numbers are not detected in constant time. For example if you check numbers up to a million, there are plenty that are products of two primes > 500.

Comment: constant time O(1) is only for the most fortunate case, the rest is O(sqrt(n))

Answer (score 0):

The maximum execution time of this algorithm is O (sqrt (n)), which will be achieved if n is prime or the product of two large prime numbers.

Average execution time is tricky; I'd say something like O (sqrt (n) / log n), because there are not that many numbers with only large prime factors.

Comment: regarding average case: for those who wonder why -
On interval [0,n] there are aprox n/ln(n) prime numbers. 
For the algo in questioProbability of a prime number